# Get field from first table by foreign key from second

Tags: mysql

Two tables: categories, and their many-to-many relations:

```
categories
id | name
1    first
2    second
3    third

relations
parent | child
1        2
1        3
```

How can I get this result?:

```
first | second
first | third
```

I only can

```
SELECT c.name, r.child 
FROM categories AS c 
LEFT JOIN relations AS r ON c.id = r.parent
```

And result is

```
first | 2
first | 3
```

So, how can I get child name in this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.name, c2.name
FROM relations AS r
LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON r.parent = c1.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON r.child = c2.id
WHERE c1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select `categories` table twice.

```
select parent_c.name parent, child_c.name child
from categories parent_c, categories child_c, relations r
where r.parent = parent_c.id and r.child = child_c.id
```